# In a time varying magnetic field why is the current flowing through a conducting wire connecting two points of a closed conducting loop zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

In a Time Varying Magnetic Field like the one shown in the picture below,

[image]

if we connect two points on the closed conducting loop using a conducting wire, why is the current flowing zero ?

My textbook says something like "the emf and the potential drop across the connected points will cancel each other out". But I could not understand the meaning of the statement. Can someone please clarify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Superposition Theorem:** The total current in any part of a linear circuit equals the algebraic sum of the currents produced by each source separately.

[image]

Let resistance per unit angle subtended at the center (in radians)  of conducting loop be $\lambda$.

Total EMF ($E_{total}$ ) around a circular path in a TVMF is $ \dfrac{d\phi}{dt}=A \dfrac{dB}{dt} $ (where $A$ is the area of the circle)

We join points A and B on the loop. Suppose AB subtends an angle $\theta$ at the centre C.

Now considering only minor arc :

$E_{AB,minor}=\dfrac{E_{total}\theta}{2\pi}$

$i_{AB,minor}=\dfrac{E_{total}\theta}{2\pi \lambda \theta}=\dfrac{E_{total}}{2\pi \lambda }$

$E_{AB,major}=\dfrac{E_{total}(2\pi-\theta)}{2\pi}$

$i_{AB,major}=\dfrac{E_{total}(2\pi-\theta)}{2\pi \lambda (2\pi-\theta)}=\dfrac{E_{total}}{2\pi \lambda }$

Now, in the connecting wire AB currents $i_{AB,major}$ and $i_{AB,minor}$ are in opposite directions and cancel each other out, giving a net current of $0$ in the wire by **Superposition Theorem**.